# List Validation does not show Error when Conditions are not met

Tags: 2010, column, validation

I am using List Validation feature for a list which is working fine i.e. doesn't save the item when condition not met. However, it is not showing the error message which helps to rectify the inputs in the column.

Is there a solution to this?

Reply to @ashwnacharya

Thanks!!

Answers to your questions

1. Choice
2. =Date-Created_Date>1
3. I am using Smart List Pro (InfowiseSolutions.com)

**Back to point 2 -**

> When I click on add new item select 15/1/2012 in the column 'First
>   date' (choice column). But since today 16/1/2012 item should not be
>   saved as it does not pass validation rule - So the page reloads but no
>   error message is shown.
>
> From the screenshots you have given, the error which is shown is in red is
>   nowhere to be seen on my list.

Comment: Sorry, per the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)  we do not accept questions about commercial, third-party products.  Instead, please ask your question using Infowise's support site: http://www.infowisesolutions.com/support.aspx. This question will be closed once the bounty expires.

Comment: @KitMenke - I am not facing any issues with third party product and have not asked any related question. I have just replied to question being asked by ashwnacharya - The real issue is with Validation Setting which is an inbuilt feature of SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Ah ok. What is Smart List Pro being used for? It looks like it comes with Column Validation as well? Just trying to understand the question..

Comment: I usually use it for Column Level Permission. However, I think the real issue is that list is unable to post any error when condition is not met for Validation.

Comment: Is it because of the Smart List Pro? I think you might have tried this. But if not, could you try removing the Smart List Pro and try validation again? or try doing this to a site in the farm where Smart List Pro is not installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of questions:

- What column data type are you using?
- What column validation formula are you using?
- Just to be sure, are you using the OOTB column validation feature and
  not some custom validation feature? If so, did you specify the user message property?

I am able to create a simple number column, and set a validation formula as follows[image]

And, when I try to set an invalid value to the column, the specified error message shows up as expected.
[image]

EDIT:

It seems that you are using Date values in a choice column. You cannot use the '-' operator in that case, since the value will be considered a string. Can't you use a date column to store dates  instead?  Use another calculated column to check the difference in days, and use that calculated column value to set the choice.

Comment: Please read answers to your question above. Thanks!!

Comment: The issue I am facing is why no error message is shown?

Answer (score 4):

When you create an item, the creation date is not set so it can't be used in condition.
You can use the current date to do what you want, or a combinaison of the current date and creation date to cover both creation and edit.

Comment: When the condition is not met its an error & hence item is not submitted into the list. That works perfectly well. However, no error is shown only the page is reloaded and due to this user is clueless on what is happening! My problem is that why error is not shown?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use branding on the site ? The validation error elements could be affected by custom styles.

Search through the source of your page using developer tools or firebug and see if the message is there.

Comment: No, I am not using any branding.

Answer (score 1):

Go to list setting and select the particular column you want to validate.
select validation and specify your formula here instead of go to list setting and then to validation setting.